# Reading values from sqlite db returns an empty array

Tags: android, sqliteopenhelper

Im trying to create an sqlite table with the following query.

```
"CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_COMPLIANCE_STATUS + "("
        + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
        + KEY_YEAR + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_DELAYED_COMPLIANCE + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_NOT_COMPLIED + " TEXT" + ")";
```

Im adding values to db using the following code

`db.addComplianceStatus(new ComplianceStatusModel(i, String.valueOf(year), String.valueOf(delayedCompliance), String.valueOf(notCompliance)));`

Im reading the contents of db as follows,

```
List<ComplianceStatusModel>  notifications = db.getAllComplianceStatus();
for (ComplianceStatusModel notify : notifications) {
    String log = "Id: "+notify.getId()+" ,Description: " + notify.getYear() + " ,Date: " + notify.getDelayedCompliance();
    // Writing Compliances to log
    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),log,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

This returns an empty array. What could be my error? When I tried printing Logging the db, it prints the memory address though.

Following is my getAllComplianceModel method

```
public List<ComplianceStatusModel> getAllComplianceStatus() {
        List<ComplianceStatusModel> complianceStatusModelList = new ArrayList<ComplianceStatusModel>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_COMPLIANCE_STATUS;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                ComplianceStatusModel complianceStatusModel = new ComplianceStatusModel();

                complianceStatusModel.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                complianceStatusModel.setYear(cursor.getString(1));
                complianceStatusModel.setDelayedCompliance(cursor.getString(2));
                complianceStatusModel.setNotComplied(cursor.getString(3));

                complianceStatusModelList.add(complianceStatusModel);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return complianceStatusModelList;
    }
```

Following is addComplianceStatus method

```
public void addComplianceStatus(ComplianceStatusModel complianceStatus) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(KEY_ID, complianceStatus.getId());
    contentValues.put(KEY_YEAR, complianceStatus.getYear());
    contentValues.put(KEY_DELAYED_COMPLIANCE, complianceStatus.getDelayedCompliance());
    contentValues.put(KEY_NOT_COMPLIED, complianceStatus.getNotComplied());
}
```

Comment: important to see your getAllComplianceStatus() method...

Comment: and Your addComplianceStatusModel().....

Comment: i have updated my question

Comment: Do You get any crash or error stacktrace? If You store this database not inside internal storage, have You set the permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE?

Comment: and are You sure Your database and table is created?

Comment: im saving it in internal storage

Comment: ok please post Your addComilanceStatus() method too...

Comment: see my answer. You have not used sqLiteDatabase.insert() method for Your content values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not added the method to store Your values in Your table. in Your `addCompilanceStatus()` method. You need to add:

```
public void addComplianceStatus(ComplianceStatusModel complianceStatus) {
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

contentValues.put(KEY_ID, complianceStatus.getId());
contentValues.put(KEY_YEAR, complianceStatus.getYear());
contentValues.put(KEY_DELAYED_COMPLIANCE, complianceStatus.getDelayedCompliance());
contentValues.put(KEY_NOT_COMPLIED, complianceStatus.getNotComplied());

sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_COMPLIANCE_STATUS, null, contentValues); //YOU HAVE FORGOT THIS
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a space in the create table statement before the brackets:
    TABLE_COMPLIANCE_STATUS + "(" -> TABLE_COMPLIANCE_STATUS + " ("

Comment: still the same problem persists

Comment: try SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase(); instead of SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

Comment: egtWritableDatabase will give also a readable one. It´s needed to write the values inside the database, so getReadableDatabase() will not give the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You miss a semi-colon in the create sqlite statement

```
"CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_COMPLIANCE_STATUS + "("
        + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
        + KEY_YEAR + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_DELAYED_COMPLIANCE + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_NOT_COMPLIED + " TEXT" + ");";
```

To test if the database is created.

```
        DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mockContext);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Log.d("my_db_test", dbHelper.getDatabaseName()));
```

To test the database version. (continue from the previous code)

```
        Log.d("my_db_test", db.getVersion()));
```

To test the column in the table (continue from the previous code)

```
        Cursor dbCursor = db.query(YOUR_TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        String[] columnNames = dbCursor.getColumnNames();
        Log.d("my_db_test", "columns names: \n");
        for(int i = 0; i < columnNames.length; i++){
            Log.d("my_db_test", "columnNames " + i + ": " + columnNames[i] + "\n");
        }
```

If all the tests are passed, then the table is created correctly. Then you should check the save and load method.

I use the code below to save the records in database

```
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DatabaseHelper.P_NAME, person.getName());
        values.put(DatabaseHelper.P_AGE, person.getAge());
        values.put(DatabaseHelper.P_COUNTRY, person.getCountry());
        isAdded = db.insert(YOUR_TABLE_NAME, null, values) > 0;
```

And use the codes to load all the records

```
        Cursor cursor = db.query(YOUR_TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            Person p = new Person();
            p.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseHelper.P_ID)));
            p.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseHelper.P_NAME)));
            p.setAge(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseHelper.P_AGE)));
            p.setCountry(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseHelper.P_COUNTRY)));
            personList.add(p);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct, the table is still created, but we need to keep a good coding practice, right?

Comment: You are wright, to do complete work, it´s good. But it will not fix the problem from the questioner.

Comment: I type this answer before he/she uploads the code, so I need to guess what's the problem in his/her situation. As a result, I suggest to check the work step by step. And the semi colon is just the beginning

Comment: i used your code to check if table is created and it is created but when i try to get the values inside the table, it returns an empty list

Comment: There's two possibility cause such an error - save incorrectly / load incorrectly. and as @Opiatefuchs mentioned above, we need your add method to further investigate the problem. By the way, if you just need some simple database operations, it's better to use the build in methods instead of rawQuery.